# Custom DatePicker by setFieldvalues Antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I'm trying to customize DatePicker for data format before submitting. I use setFielsValue to override its value but it is not working.
I need to find a way to customize component and data format before submitting.

**Create Form**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Input, Select } from 'antd';
import { t } from 'i18next';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  closeModalAction,
  saveDraftAction
} from '../../../redux/modal/actions';
import { draftSelector } from '../../../redux/modal/selectors';
import { getAllPositionsAction } from '../../../redux/positions/actions';
import {
  createEmployeeAction,
  uploadImageAction
} from '../../../redux/employees/actions';
import CustomUpload from '../../../components/common/CustomUpload';
import CustomDatePicker from '../../../components/common/CustomDatePicker';

const { Option } = Select;

const Create = ({
  form,
  createEmployee,
  positions,
  closeModal,
  id,
  saveDraft,
  getAllPosition,
  draft
}) => {
  const {
    validateFields,
    getFieldDecorator,
    setFieldsValue,
    getFieldsValue
  } = form;
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateFields((error, values) => {
      console.log(values);
      if (!error) {
        createEmployee({
          employee: {
            name: values.name,
            job: values.job,
            email: values.email,
            birthday: values.birthday,
            dayInCompany: values.dayInCompany,
            imgURL: values.imgURL
          }
        });
        closeModal(id);
      }
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (draft) {
      setFieldsValue(draft);
    }
    return () => {
      const values = getFieldsValue();
      saveDraft({ data: values, id });
    };
  }, [draft, getFieldsValue, id, saveDraft, setFieldsValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPosition();
  }, [getAllPosition]);

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <Form.Item label="Employee Id" colon={false}>
        {getFieldDecorator('id', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter email' }]
        })(<Input />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Email" colon={false}>
        {getFieldDecorator('email', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter email' }]
        })(<Input />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Name" colon={false}>
        {getFieldDecorator('name', {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter email' }]
        })(<Input />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <CustomDatePicker
        {...{ form }}
        label="Start Work Date"
        colon={false}
        src="dayInCompany"
        required
        message="Please enter date"
      />
      <CustomDatePicker
        {...{ form }}
        label="BirthDay"
        colon={false}
        src="birthday"
        required
        message="Please enter date"
      />
      <Form.Item label="Position" colon={false}>
        {getFieldDecorator('job', {
          rules: [
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please select your job!'
            }
          ]
        })(
          <Select>
            {positions.map(position => (
              <Option key={position.id} value={position.name}>
                {position.name}
              </Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <CustomUpload
        {...{ form }}
        label="Avatar"
        src="imgURL"
        colon={false}
        message="Please up your image"
        required
      />
      <Form.Item>
        <Button onClick={() => closeModal(id)}>{t('button.cancel')}</Button>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          {t('button.create')}
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

Create.propTypes = {
  form: PropTypes.any,
  closeModal: PropTypes.func,
  createEmployee: PropTypes.func,
  draft: PropTypes.object,
  saveDraft: PropTypes.func,
  id: PropTypes.number,
  positions: PropTypes.array,
  getAllPosition: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  uploadImage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

Create.defaultProps = {
  positions: []
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  draft: draftSelector(state, props),
  positions: state.positions.positions
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  closeModal: id => dispatch(closeModalAction(id)),
  createEmployee: params => dispatch(createEmployeeAction(params)),
  saveDraft: params => dispatch(saveDraftAction(params)),
  getAllPosition: () => dispatch(getAllPositionsAction()),
  uploadImage: (file, onSuccess) => dispatch(uploadImageAction(file, onSuccess))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Form.create()(Create));
```

**CustomeDatePicker** with setFieldsValue

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form, DatePicker } from 'antd';

const CustomDatePicker = ({ form, label, src, colon, required, message }) => {
  console.log(form);
  const { getFieldDecorator, setFieldsValue } = form;

  const handleChange = e => {
    const date = new Date(e).getTime();
    setFieldsValue({
      [src]: date
    });
  };
  return (
    <Form.Item label={label} colon={colon}>
      {getFieldDecorator(src, {
        rules: [
          {
            required,
            message
          }
        ]
      })(<DatePicker onChange={handleChange} />)}
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

CustomDatePicker.propTypes = {
  form: PropTypes.shape({
    getFieldDecorator: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    setFieldsValue: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }),
  label: PropTypes.string,
  src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  colon: PropTypes.bool,
  required: PropTypes.bool,
  message: PropTypes.string
};

CustomDatePicker.defaultProps = {
  colon: true,
  required: false,
  message: null
};

export default CustomDatePicker;
```

Please help me some way to make it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

AntD's DatePicker component has a [format prop](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-format) that accepts a [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) format string.  The DatePicker only accepts a momentjs object as a valid value, so setting it to a string or JS Date as you are now will not work.